# Android Studio ADB error

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio

I keep getting this error when I start Android Studio. I am running Ubuntu, I did a fresh install and this happened upon start up.

> ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill
>   "adb" and click 'Restart'

I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381790/adb-not-responding-wait-more-or-kill-adb-or-restart-ubuntu-13-64-bit) this solution.

I tried making an AVD, and it doesn't want to run on there. I double checked that ADB is added to my PATH.

Is there more information I can provide? Any response with information or questions is helpful.

Comment: Nothing worked for me until at last [this](http://www.nguyenvanquan7826.com/2015/12/12/fix-adb-not-responding-if-youd-like-to-retry-then-please-manually-kill-adb-and-click-restart/?lang=en) solved the problem The idea is: perhaps you are using a 32bit OS and platform-tools has updated to 23.1. The solution thenis to go back to platform-tools 23.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Close Android Studio and kill all processes using port 5037

1. `sudo lsof -i | grep 5037`
2. `sudo kill [PID_NUMBER]`
3. open Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while configuring Android Studio. I tried following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

If that doesn't helps make sure that "adb" in "AndroidStudioSdk/platform-tools/" folder is executable. If its executables permission are not set than set it with following command.

```
chmod uog+x abd
```

Hopes this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem but under a Linux system (32-bit), after searching t'interweb and finding nothing that helped me I went about fixing this issue myself.

I found that if I try to execute certain binaries that are bundled with Android Studio they would not execute, infact both adb and java threw the same error:

> java/adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

The fix for java is to use the system jdk not the one bundled with Android Studio.
So I thought what the hell and changed the bundled adb binary.

First thing is to backup the bundled adb:

```
mv '/path/to/bundled/adb' '/path/to/bundled/adb~'
```

I then symlinked my system adb to Android Studio's sdk folder:
(your systems adb may be in a different location)

```
ln -s '/usr/bin/adb' '/path/to/bundled/adb'
```

And voila it works!
I think it may be due to the binaries being for a 64-bit CPU but I dunno, can anyone confirm this??